# Resize and reposition the application created using createprocess?

Tags: c, winapi, resize, overriding, createprocess

I'm executing an application say notepad, using createprocess.

I need to override the default size and position of that application so i modified STARTUPINFO, and specified dwX,dwY,dwYSize,dwXSize and added STARTF_USEPOSITION||STARTF_USESIZE to dwFlags.

But the application is not opening at all.
If i put one of STARTF_USEPOSITION  and STARTF_USESIZE, the application opens but not reposition or resize.

Is there anyway to do that??

```
{
STARTUPINFO         siStartupInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcessInfo;


memset(&siStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartupInfo));
memset(&piProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcessInfo));

siStartupInfo.cb = sizeof(siStartupInfo);
siStartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USEPOSITION|STARTF_USESIZE;//||STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
siStartupInfo.wShowWindow=SW_SHOWDEFAULT;
siStartupInfo.dwX=900;
siStartupInfo.dwY=300;
siStartupInfo.dwXSize=1000;
siStartupInfo.dwYSize=1000;

if(CreateProcess("H:\\WINXP\\system32\\notepad.exe",     // Application name
                 NULL ,                 // Application arguments
                 0,
                 0,
                 FALSE,
                 NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                 0,
                 0,                              // Working directory
                 &siStartupInfo,
                 &piProcessInfo) )
    printf("Sucessful\n");
else
    printf("Error");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have "STARTF_USEPOSITION||STARTF_USESIZE" with two bars? It should be one bar. Apart from that you'll probably need to show us the code you use.

Comment: My bad,i've changed the operator. it now opens but still window size and position remains unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

Application may ignore all data in `STARTUPINFO`, or use only `wShowWindow`.

You can try to use `WaitForInputIdle`, then `FindWindow` and then `SetWindowPos`.

Comment: I've gone till SetWindowPos , but its nor repainting the notepad accordingly, the notepad opens in its default position and size but a small frame is created at position specified. I'm not sure what uFlags should i use.

Comment: SetWindowPos fails, returns 0.

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan, it also returns an error, check `GetLastError`.

Comment: ,its 1400, supposedly invalid window handle error. If possible can you provide me the remaining code, which involves,WaitForInputIdle,FindWindow and SetWindowPos, for the program i wrote.

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan, no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems notepad is not using `GetStartupInfo()` to read the `STARTUPINFO` passed in when it's created. Something I have done in the past to get round this is to pass a valid `PROCESS_INFORMATION` to `CreateProcess`.

From this, you will be able to get out the created process' PID. You can then poll with `EnumWindows` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId` until you find the window. This is more accurate than `FindWindow`, which potentially would match against other instances of notepad.